# Lazy Load cell image for programmatically created tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading

I am creating a number of tableviews programmatically.  The client has specifically asked for a layout that is not a UITableView Controller.  Something like:

[image]

The number of tableviews as well as the number of items in each table varies.  All of the tables are created at once when the view loads.  I would like to add thumbnails to the cells in the table views.  I need find a way to lazy load the thumbnails.  I have successfully implemented a lazy load on a UITableViewController.  My prior success is in part because I can use the [tableview reloadData] call to indicate the cell thumbnails can be displayed after the images have been cached.  How might I implement a lazy load to the tableviews created programmatically?  My initial idea is to add some sort of selector to the table view in order to update a cell once the images have been cached for a particular cell.  I am not sure how this would work and would appreciate any help.

The following is the code that I use to create the table views programmatically (I am using ARC):

```
@interface SyllabusSegmentedViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UIScrollView *SyllabusSegmentedSV;
```

--

```
@implementation SyllabusSegmentedViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   // Programmatic creation of the table views and titles for Table Views 
   [self ProgramaticCreationOfTableView:self];
}

-(void) ProgramaticCreationOfTableView:(id)sender {
    for (numTableViews = 0; numTableViews < [syllabusDispayed.LevelNames count]; numTableViews ++) {

    // Create Table View
    UITableView *newTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    newTableView = [self createTableView:self];

    // Create UILabel that will act as Title for Each table view
    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:[self MakeHeaderLabelFrame:numTableViews workingTableView:newTableView]];
    [newLabel setBackgroundColor:nil];
    newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    newLabel.text = [syllabusDispayed.LevelNames objectAtIndex:numTableViews];
    newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    newLabel.font = font;
    newLabel.textColor = color;


    [newTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    newTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    newTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    newTableView.frame = ([self MakeTableViewFrame:numTableViews workingTableView:newTableView]);

    newTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    newLabel.autoresizingMask     = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [SyllabusSegmentedSV addSubview:newTableView];
    [SyllabusSegmentedSV addSubview:newLabel];
    }
  }

-(UITableView *)createTableView:(id)sender {
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numTableViews];

    return tableView;
 }

-(CGRect)MakeHeaderLabelFrame:(int)workingTableNumber workingTableView:(UITableView *)newTableView {
    int numberOfPreviousLevelsRows = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < workingTableNumber ; i ++) {
    numberOfPreviousLevelsRows += [[syllabusDispayed.SyllabusDictionary objectForKey:[syllabusDispayed.LevelNames objectAtIndex:i]] count];
    }

    return CGRectMake(0, 75 + ((workingTableNumber * 80) + (numberOfPreviousLevelsRows *55)), self.view.bounds.size.width, 25);
 }


-(CGRect)MakeTableViewFrame:(int)workingTableNumber workingTableView:(UITableView *)newTableView {
    int numberOfPreviousLevelsRows = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < workingTableNumber ; i ++) {
     numberOfPreviousLevelsRows += [[syllabusDispayed.SyllabusDictionary objectForKey:[syllabusDispayed.LevelNames objectAtIndex:i]] count];
     }

    return CGRectMake(0, 95 + ((workingTableNumber * 80) + (numberOfPreviousLevelsRows *55)), self.view.bounds.size.width, 65*[newTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]);
 }
```

I also have implemented the necessary function for a UITableViewDelegate such as

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Why you can't simply use few sections separated by header with constant size instead of creation tableViews?

Comment: @Mikhail - I'm not positive what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit? Do you mean instead of using individual grouped tableviews themselves, I should use the sections of a UITableViewController?

Comment: @Mikhail I agree that would be much easier, unfortunately the client asked for a layout exactly as I have included in the screenshot.

Comment: Fortunately, it can be achieved by using multiple sections :)

Comment: What you're showing in your screenshot looks like a single grouped table view with section headers. Perhaps your client doesn't know what a grouped table view looks like.

Comment: The screen shot shows two individual grouped table views.  Are you suggesting that I may be able to achieve the same results using a single grouped tableview?

Comment: Yes of course. It can be a grouped table view with multiple sections with header views.

Comment: And would you suggest using a UITableViewController or a UIViewController?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The only reason not to use a table view controller is if don't want the table view to take up the whole screen below the navigation bar. The screenshot you show could be achieved with a UITableViewController.

Comment: I see you've asked a new question related to this one (I presume) about multiple table views. Are you still trying to do it that way instead of one table view with sections? If so, why? Doing it with one table view will be more straight forward.

Comment: No, I can see why you might presume the questions are pertaining to the same problem, but they were actually questions aimed at completely separate problems.  Thank you for your comments, I ended up going with a single grouped tableView and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at library [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

I think this is what you are looking for.

But may be the real problem with your approach: i guess that it is not really necessary to create multiple TableViews that located one after another - it's case where sections may do the thing.

**EDIT**

TableViewDataSource has method named `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Also by implementing `– tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` or `– tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`  you can get necessary space between sections.

You should implement all this methods in SyllabusSegmentedViewController.

Comment: Thank you. A single grouped tableView with multiple sections was the solution.